# Replacing fixtures created in Body Editor Loader for character animation

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-engine, game-physics

I am making a game using LibGDX and Box2D. I use Physics Body Editor to create fixtures for my game character. I would like to change fixtures during the player walking animation, because his posture is slightly changing, of course. 
I have no idea how can I do it. I thought about destroying the fixture and then using the other one from loader file, but I can't access fixture directly, because I am not declaring it manually.
If you need more info I will give it to you.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The fixtures are being declared manually as one or more polygons in the loader file. Its just not done by code you have written. Have a look at the file named BodyEditorLoader and you should get an idea of how the fixtures are being created. You should be able to access the fixtures of the body by looping through all the fixtures returned by

```
Body.getFixtureList()
```

You will be able to access any element you need to...shapes, vertices etc and make any changes you need to.